# Will gcc functions in string.h break UTF-8 string?

Tags: c, string, gcc, utf-8

I don't know the following cases in GCC, who can help me?

1. Whether a valid UTF-8 character (except code point `0`) still contains zero byte? If so, I think function such as `strlen` will break that UTF-8 character.
2. Whether a valid UTF-8 character contains a byte whose value is equal to `'\n'`? If so, I think function such as "gets" will break that UTF-8 character.
3. Whether a valid UTF-8 character contains a byte whose value is equal to `' '` or `'\t'`? If so, I think function such as `scanf("%s%s")` will break that UTF-8 character and be interpreted as two or more words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to all your questions are the same: **No**.

It's one of the advantages of UTF-8: all ASCII bytes do not occur when encoding non-ASCII code points into UTF-8.

For example, you can safely use `strlen` on a UTF-8 string, only that its result is the number of bytes instead of UTF-8 code points.